# How to get rid of the taste of flour in homemade bakery?

Tags: baking, flavor, cake, flour, cookies

I usually get random cookie and cake recipes from the internet and try them. They are good but all of them have floury taste to me. Possible culprits are the flour I use and how I mix and bake dough. I use Gold Medal All-Purpose Flour and my hands to mix ingredients, having no mixer. What can I get wrong? Is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you aren't very unlucky and happen to download a series of bad recipes I think it's one of a few things.

It's possible you could be undercooking your goods. Fully cooked baked goods should not taste like flour.

It's also possible that you could be mixing insufficiently. If this were the case though you'd  likely have some cookies that weren't floury.

The most likely culprit though is packed flour. If you are using volume measurements (most likely given the source) for flour, it's quite possible to use nearly twice as much flour as the recipe intends simply because your flour is packed down more than the author's was.

I recommend using either a food processor or a sifter to sift your flour adequately before measuring. Don't undo your sifting by rapping your measuring cup on the counter either! Simply scoop, scrape to level and dump it in the mixing bowl.

See Also:

- [What Kinds of Recipes Should I Sift/Aerate The Flour?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5476/what-kinds-of-recipes-should-i-sift-aerate-the-flour)
- [How can I make sifting easier?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5364/how-can-i-make-sifting-easier)
- [What is the purpose of sifting dry ingredients?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5273/sifting-dry-ingredients)

Comment: Better yet, find a recipe that measures the flour by weight.

Comment: I had never understood the need of sifting flour before measuring. Thanks a lot. I will try with the same recipe and see the result. First, I have to buy a sifter and, probably, a proper cookbook.

Comment: Alternatively, convert the recipes to weight. Flour is around 120g (4¼ oz) per cup, depending on measurement method. And once you've converted a recipe, you can make it again in the future with near perfect consistency.

Comment: You shouldn't have to buy a sifter if you own a whisk. Just get a bowl and stir it around with a whisk, works nicely. :)

Comment: @puri: there's a rumor over here that in ancient times it had the purpose to sift out mealworms & Co...

Answer (score 3):

I've only ever had this issue if I under cook the baked item. 
You get the same issue if you don't cook your roux long enough.

Answer (score 3):

My grandmother was born in 1909 in New Zealand. She moved to the UK and started her family. When we were young she was always busy in the kitchen, making bread, cake, lemon curd, fruit scones...… she would allow the mix to sit, somewhere cool before she cooked the scones. It made all the difference. I tried her recipe which the family recorded, my father's verdict.... 'its a bit floury!' and the reason? I hadn't allowed the mix to sit long enough- I was too impatient. SO my suggestion, try setting the mix aside for several hours and seeing if it makes a difference. Same with making pastry. You would mix it, roll it out on grease proof paper and then stick in the fridge for a few hours of the next day before using. Its funny because this is how things were done 100 years ago- and none of the modern recipes either online or in cook books mention this. But it was once de rigueur!

Answer (score 0):

So my husband got this cookie recipe recently, and they just tasted like flour too. I decided to tweak the recipe I added more sugar, vanilla, and blueberries as they were blueberry cookies so I'd recommend vanilla extract, and more sugar.